# Pro's / cons of different domain serving options for community

Tags: community, custom-domain, digital-experience

We're configuring a custom domain for a Community (Digital Experience). When creating a new Domain in Salesforce, we have the choices between:

- Salesforce serves the domain over HTTPS, on Salesforce's servers, using your HTTPS certificate
- Salesforce serves the domain over HTTPS using a Salesforce content delivery network (CDN) partner and a shared or single HTTPS certificate
- A non-Salesforce host or service serves this domain over HTTPS
- Temporary non-HTTPS domain

The question is how to determine which option to use. I'm especially puzzled between the first and the second. In the past we have done this using option 1 with the CA signed SSL certificate, which works well but is quite a hassle, and needs the yearly certificate update. I see that the second option is available since Winter '19. What are the reasons not to go for this option, given that it's less pain to set up? Is it a safe choice for a community (behind a login)?

Comment: To provide more info on why I voted it as "opinion based" - we can't answer which option you, specifically, should use. That's where the opinion comes in as we don't know your situation as I'm sure there's arguments for each option depending on the use case. It seems you're partial to the 2nd option so you could focus more on your last question (is it a safe choice for a community) or asking about setting that option up in general.

Comment: Which is why I am asking for pro's and con's. I am not implying there is a best option, I need the objective pro's and cons of each option, in order to be able to make the call. I am not partial to the second option, it is just one that has an obvious advantage. Not seeing how this is not a valid question and I am curious what a valid question according to the mods would look like in this case.

Comment: Your title says pros/cons, but your last paragraph is about determining which to use and comparing option 1 & 2. There's nothing wrong with that if that's what you want to ask about, but is option 1 being a hassle an objective con? That's kind of my point about there being lots of opinion around it. Other than [existing documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_mgmt_domain_config_options.htm&type=5), I'm not sure there's much to point out as both options seem valid and "safe" really depends on what the community is going to host (ex. is 3rd party CDN ok)

Comment: Correct, it's illustrating that I have little and mostly subjective insight in the matter, which is why I am asking for objective pro's and con's that should help determining which option to choose. If it would be an answer, I would have answered it myself. If that's the big issue here, I'll gladly remove it. Again, what form would an acceptable question have in this case?

Comment: I'm not a mod and multiple community users voted on this question (It can vote to "re-open" a question when you edit it). Asking for `what are the setup differences for domain serving options in Communities` vs. `pros/cons of different domain...` is a subtle, but important difference IMO. Pros/Cons may have opinion to them, but setup steps are fact-based (ex. less steps != better).  "Safe" is another word that is difficult to assess without knowing your community use case and security concern (ex. As long as it's not a risk, is it safe)?